# "username@host" is colored white for specific user but not others

Tags: ssh

This is how it looks like:
[image: This is how it looks like.]

This is how it should look like:
[image: This is how it should look like.]

The two users both standard users with no root access. I don't know if it's related but a CLI I'm using is unable to create files when run locally, yet works fine when run remotely via `ssh`.